# How to convert csv to multiple arrays without pandas?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have an csv file like this:

```
student_id,event_id,score
1,1,20
3,1,20
4,1,18
5,1,13
6,1,18
7,1,14
8,1,14
9,1,11
10,1,19
...
```

and I need to convert it into multiple arrays/lists like I did using pandas here:

```
scores = pd.read_csv("/content/score.csv", encoding = 'utf-8', 
                      index_col = [])
student_id = scores['student_id'].values
event_id = scores['event_id'].values
score = scores['score'].values
print(scores.head())
```

As you can see, I get three arrays, which I need in order to run the data analysis. How can I do this using Python's CSV library? I have to do this without the use of pandas. Also, how can I export data from multiple new arrays into a csv file when I am done with this data? I, again, used panda to do this:

```
avg = avgScore
max = maxScore
min = minScore
sum = sumScore
id = student_id_data
    
dict = {'avg(score)': avg, 'max(score)': max, 'min(score)': min, 'sum(score)': sum, 'student_id': id}  
     
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
  
df.to_csv(r'/content/AnalyzedData.csv', index=False)
```

Those first 5 are arrays if you are wondering.

Comment: Have you tried using the csv module and read its documentation? What was the problem?

Comment: You can read each row of the csv file and append values fro the columns in one to the appropriate list (what you are calling "arrays").

Comment: @mkrieger1 i tried reading it I had no idea how to do it

Comment: @martineau I primarily use java so thats why I said array, is it "list" in python? Also how would you do that, that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Python supports both lists and arrays, but the former are built-in and more commonly used — and probably all that's needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer which will produce a separate list for each column in the CSV file.

```
import csv

csv_filepath = "score.csv"

with open(csv_filepath, "r", newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    columns = reader.fieldnames

    lists = {column: [] for column in columns}  # Lists for each column.

    for row in reader:
        for column in columns:
            lists[column].append(int(row[column]))

    for column_name, column in lists.items():
        print(f'{column_name}: {column}')
```

Sample output:

```
student_id: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
event_id: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
score: [20, 20, 18, 13, 18, 14, 14, 11, 19]
```

You also asked how to do the reverse of this. Here's an example I how is self-explanatory:

```
# Dummy sample analysis data
length = len(lists['student_id'])
avgScore = list(range(length))
maxScore = list(range(length))
minScore = list(range(length))
sumScore = list(range(length))
student_ids = lists['student_id']

csv_output_filepath = 'analysis.csv'
fieldnames = ('avg(score)', 'max(score)', 'min(score)', 'sum(score)', 'student_id')

with open(csv_output_filepath, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for values in zip(avgScore, maxScore, minScore, sumScore, student_ids):
        row = dict(zip(fieldnames, values))  # Combine into dictionary.
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for! Do you know how to do this but in reverse? Like if I did the analysis on the arrays and ended up with 5 new arrays, how do I put that into a new .csv?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to show an example of doing the reverse.

Comment: Right, thank you, I figured it out on my own yesterday, its almost the same

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do does not require the `csv` module, it's just three lines of code (one of them admittedly dense)

```
splitted_lines = (line.split(',') for line in open('/path/to/you/data.csv')
labels = next(splitted_lines)
arr = dict(zip(labels,zip(*((int(i) for i in ii) for ii in splitted_lines))))
```

1. `splitted_lines` is a *generator* that iterates over your data file one line at a time and provides you a list with the three (in your example) items in each line, line by line.
2. `next(splitted_lines)` returns the list with the (splitted) content of the first line, that is our three `labels`
3. We fit our data in a dictionary; using the class init method (i.e., by invoking `dict`) it is possible to initialize it using a generator of 2-uples, here the value of a `zip`:

   - `zip` 1st argument is `labels`, so the keys of the dictionary will be the labels of the columns
   - the 2nd argument is the result of the evaluation of an inner `zip` but in this case `zip` is used because zipping the starred form of a sequence of sequences has the effect of transposing it... so the value associated to each key will be the transpose of what follows `*` …

     - what follows the `*` is simply (the generator equivalent of) a list of lists with (in your example) 9 rows of three integer values so that

     the second argument to the 1st `zip` is consequently a sequence of *three* sequences of nine integers, that are going to be coupled to the corresponding *three* keys/`labels`

Here I have an example of using the data collected by the previous three lines of code

```
In [119]: print("\n".join("%15s:%s"%(l,','.join("%3d"%i for i in arr[l])) for l in labels))
     ...: 
     student_id:  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
       event_id:  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1
          score: 20, 20, 18, 13, 18, 14, 14, 11, 19

In [120]: print(*arr['score'])
20 20 18 13 18 14 14 11 19
```

---

PS If the question were about an assignment in a sort of Python 101 it's unlikely that my solution would be deemed acceptable

Comment: This is a great solution tysm, and it seems to work, but I do have to use the python csv library for this. Do you know a way to do that? Or make this a little simpler? It is a little complicated for me.

Comment: Re using `csv`, change the 1st line to `import csv ; splitted_lines = csv.reader('…')`, that's all.  ፨፨፨፨፨ Re simplifying my answer, [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) has provided a perfectly fine, simple and absolutely canonical [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744972/2749397) that you should accept asap — otoh my answer was meant not to fulfill your immediate needs but to give you something to study and also, I admit, to satisfy my hubris, as clearly stated in the post scriptum :-)